# Onclick Div Slider using jQuery or simple javascript

Tags: jquery, html

Iwant to slide a div onclick which has some images and inner divs, using jquery. Please help me with the code.

Comment: start with this `<script>`

Comment: end with this `</script>`

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general so i have to make some assumptions:

```
$("#bigDiv").click(function(){
  $("#bigDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

follow below tutorial. I think it will help you.

[1](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)
[3](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/12/jquery-slide-div-content-from-left-to-right.html)